# POS API with javascript possible?

Tags: square-connect

I am working on a web based POS system that is accessed on raspberry pi's. I have looked through the square docs and the only POS API seems to be for Android/iOS. Is there something I am missing? My front end is HTML/Javascript and the backend uses PHP. There are also a few small python programs running for example, to fill in text inputs like product weight with a USB connected scale.

I know square has the web form API, but that is not what I am looking for. The goal is to have cards scanned with a square card reader and then charge based on a given value. Thanks.

Comment: The docs say you can access their rest api via postman so you should be able to access it via an http client on your server https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#connectapiv2conventions

Comment: @vbranden From what I've read, to charge a card you need to generate a nonce but you can only do that with SqPaymentForm which requires entering all of the credit card fields, # CVV, date, etc. Otherwise you need a customer_id which requires one of:

given_name, 
family_name, 
company_name, 
email_address, 
phone_number. 

But I do not have any of these because customers here do not have an account. Can I just generate random nonsense for one of these fields?

Comment: Not sure but in sasl a nonce can be any one time random string so I’d imagine you can generate your own nonce as long as it meets any requirements for length

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like for this you need their nonce because it corresponds with the card you are charging and it expires after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to connect a Square card reader to your raspberry pi. You could let customers key in transactions with the e commerce APIs however.